# is duality principle in boolean algebra is true for every expression

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, binary, digital-circuits

Let say A = 1 and B = 1
and then A+B = 1
now by using duality(replacing or gate by and gate and 1 by 0) we can say that, A.B = 0
but this is not 0, because 1.1 = 1, so please anyone clear my misunderstanding here, Thank in advance

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. `A·B = 0 but this is not 0` How is 0 not 0? Not *identical result* (1), but *equivalent result*: 1 replaced by(exchanged with) 0: 0.

Comment: You incorrectly applied duality, you must also negate $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\overline{A+B}=\overline A\cdot\overline B$$

and

$$\overline{A\cdot B}=\overline A+\overline B$$

Answer (score 0):

Negation gives you $\overline{A}=0,\overline{B}=0$, so everything is ok in "and".